# An inequality $r \leq r_a+r_b+r_c$ for radii of inscribed circles in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

Let D be the inscribed circle of a triangle. There must be three other lesser inscribed circles, each touching D and two sides of the triangle.

I want to show that

$$r \leq r_a+r_b+r_c$$

All I can see is three isosceles triangles to the vertices though.
Is there an inequality regarding inscribed circles that I can make use of here?

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the angles of the vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$, respectively. From the similar  triangles seen in the diagram, we have

$$\frac{r_c}{r}=\frac{CD_c}{CD}=\frac{CD_c}{CD_c +r_c+r} $$

Use $CD_c=r_c/\sin(\gamma/2)$ to reexpress above equation in the form of ratio,

$$\frac{r_c}{r} = \frac{1-\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{1+\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}
=\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\gamma}{4}\right) $$

Similar expressions can be derived for the other two ratios. Together, we have

$$\frac{r_a+r_b+r_c}{r}= \cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\alpha}{4}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\beta}{4}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\gamma}{4}\right)$$

Use the fact that, for $0<\theta<\pi/2$, $\cot^2(\theta)$ is a convex function to establish the inequality below,

$$\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\alpha}{4}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\beta}{4}\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi+\gamma}{4}\right)$$
$$ \ge 3\cot^2\left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{12} \right) = 3\cot^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right) = 1$$

In the end, we have,
$$r_a+r_b+r_c \ge r$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Do you think there's any way I could avoid the cot function?